# Touchswipe not initiated correctly after JQM page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, touchswipe

I'm creating a hybrid app using JQM. One of the pages is an image gallery where I use [Touchswipe](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin).

If I open the page directly everything works fine. But if I navigate to this page by clicking a link from another page, JQM loads the page using Ajax and `swipe` is not initialized correctly. If I try to swipe, I get this error:

[image]

It only works if I hit F5 and reload the page.

This is the code I use:

```
$(document).on( "pagecontainerbeforeshow", function( e, ui ) {
  Gallery.init();
});

var Gallery = {
  imgContainer: null,
  (...),

  init: function() {
    this.imgContainer = $('#imageContainer');
    (...)
    console.log('This msg shows');

    this.imgContainer.swipe({
        threshold        : 100,
        triggerOnTouchEnd: true,
        allowPageScroll  : "horizontal",
        swipeStatus      : function (event, phase, direction, distance, duration) {
            Gallery.swipe(event, phase, direction, distance, duration)
        }
    });
  },

  swipe: function(...){
    console.log('I only get this by hitting F5');
  }

};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It could be that pagecontainerbeforeshow is unable to fire the (Gallery.init();) because the page is not in the Dom yet.  change ($(document).on( "pagecontainerbeforeshow") to ($(document).on( "pagecontainertransition")  and see if it helps

Comment: Nope, still get the same error. `Gallery.init()`fires. It even runs `this.imgContainer.swipe()`, but then I get this error.

Comment: check here to see if you have plugins loaded in the correct way -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794927/jquery-mobile-touchswipe-jquery-plugin-errors

Comment: I wish it was that simple. Unfortunately it's loaded after jQuery and JQM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that it WAS the order of the scripts loaded. But not as [described in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794927/jquery-mobile-touchswipe-jquery-plugin-errors).

Initially I was loading my script on my gallery page:

```
// Header
<script src=jquery
<script src=jquery.mobile

//Footer
<script src=jquery.touchSwipe
```

But because JQM retrieves pages using Ajax, touchSwipe is never loaded. So by adding it to my index, it's already loaded when JQM fetches the apge, I still need to "load it" on my gallery page as well, just in case the app is closed and reopened on that page.